# Unable to access middleman node that has a reverse SSH tunnel to an MSSQL server behind corporate firewall

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, networking

I need to access an MSSQL machine behind corporate firewall through an AWS EC2 instance AS IF the EC2 instance IS the MSSQL machine. For our purposes, I call the EC2 instance the "middleman" node.

I plan to do this using SSH tunnels (let me know if you know of a better solution).

This is what we have:

1. **MSSQL machine** - behind corporate firewall, cannot access the Internet.
2. **Terminal machine** - behind corporate firewall, can access the Internet and the database machine.
3. **AWS EC2 instance ("middleman")** - accessible on the Internet. Open ports: 22, 14430.

I need to connect to the MSSQL machine (e.g. via SQLWorkbenchJ, or a JDBC connection) through the middleman node. The goal is to access the middleman node *AS IF* it is the MSSQL machine behind corporate firewall.

For a start, I'm making the middleman node accessible on the Internet. Eventually, I plan to make the middleman node accessible only to the replication EC2 instance provisioned by AWS Data Migration Service.

This is the contents of the middleman /etc/ssh_config file:

```
cat /etc/ssh_config

TCPKeepAlive yes
ClientAliveInterval 240
ClientAliveCountMax 99999
GatewayPorts yes
```

I have rebooted the middleman EC2 instance multiple times.

The MSSQL machine cannot access the Internet directly, we have to do so via the terminal machine.

On the terminal machine (running Windows 2008 and Cygwin), I ran:

```
nohup ssh -i /cygdrive/c/Sync/middleman.pem -f -N -R 14330:private_hostname_of_mssql_machine:1433 ec2-user@public_hostname_of_middleman_machine
```

On the middleman node (running AWS Linux and mssql cli), I have **NO** problems running:

```
mssql -s localhost -o 14330 -u username -p password -d database_name
```

**I have no issues right up to this stage.** I can access the MSSQL server on the middleman node in an SSH shell via the mssql tool with no issues.

However, I am NOT able to make a connection on my laptop to the middleman node:

```
mssql -s public_hostname_of_middleman_machine -o 14330 -u username -p password -d database_name
```

The error message I got is:

```
Error: Failed to connect to public_hostname_of_middleman_machine:14330 - connect ECONNREFUSED ip_of_middleman_machine:1433
```

I've checked - mssql can contact the hostname of the middleman machine on the Internet (otherwise it will return a "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND" error). The connection is refused for other reasons.

I need to replicate the MSSQL database using AWS DMS, and need the replication server to point to the middleman node (I am not able to set up a reverse SSH tunnel to the replication server directly)

Comment: Okay now that I've had coffee and can actually read the question properly. Is your corp firewall and the database corp firewall different? Why is the EC2 instance able to access the database if as you mentioned it has no internet access? Also your corp firewall could potentially be blocking outbound to the EC2 instance port 14330 while allowing SSH to go through.